# How do I fix multiple declaration and multiple initialization errors?

Tags: c++

Sample 1>

```
namespace Exercise {
    int ivar = 0;
}

int ivar = 0;    
using Exercise::ivar; // <<== error
```

error C2874: using-declaration causes a multiple declaration of 'Exercise::ivar'

Sample 2>

```
namespace Exercise {
    double dvar = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    using Exercise::dvar;

    double dvar = 3.1416; // <<== error
}

error C2374: 'Exercise::dvar' : redefinition; multiple initialization
```

I have difficulties to understand these errors. can someone give me a little detail?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace Exercise {
    int ivar = 0; // create a new variable "::Exercise::ivar"
}
int ivar = 0;    // create a new variable ::ivar;
using Exercise::ivar; // add name "::ivar" to variable "::Exercise::ivar", but that name is taken!
```

next example:

```
namespace Exercise {
    double dvar = 0; // create a new variable "::Exercise::dvar"
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    using Exercise::dvar; // add name "::_tmain(...)::dvar" to variable "::Exercise::dvar" 
    double dvar = 3.1416; // create a new variable "::_tmain(...)::dvar", but that name is taken!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`using` pulls the specified item into the current namespace.  So in Sample 1, you will get something called `ivar`, so this will clash with the local variable that you try to call `ivar`.

Answer (score 0):

change ivar and dvar inside of namespace Excercise by appending a character or a number to the variables, then run your code.  The error message:

`error C2374: 'Exercise::dvar' : redefinition; multiple initialization`

Is pretty clear, you've reinitialized with the same name.

In the first example (sample 1) you've declared int `ivar=0;` the compiler sees that `ivar` is already in the `Excercise` namespace.

You can change sample 1 to this:

```
namespace Exercise {    
       int ivar2 = 0;
}
int ivar = 0;    
using Exercise::ivar2; // <<== no error
```

The second sample is left as an excercise to you.  In addition, Your variable names are duplicated.

If you just need to initialize them go ahead and initialize them rather then redeclaring them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set an existing variable? Then do not redefine it.

```
using Exercise::dvar;
dvar = 3.1416;
```